# Randomising background of a div

Tags: javascript, html, background

I'm trying to randomise the background of a div by adding a script into the html. My css sheet linked does not prescribe any background image or colour but has some webkit transition.

I did look for some solution but its not really working -

```
<div id="maincontent">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

            var images =["lockimg1.jpg","lockimg2.jpg","lockimg3.jpg","lockimg4.jpg","lockimg5.jpg","lockimg6.jpg","lockimg7.jpg"];

            $(document.getElementById('maincontent').css({'backgroundimage':'url('+ images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)]+')'});

              )};
        </script>
```

On my css sheet, the "maincontent" div has the following -

```
#maincontent{
    padding:20%; 
    display:flex;
    width:100vm;
    height:100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background:url(lockimg2.jpg);
    background-blend-mode: darken;
    background-size:contain;
      opacity:0.98;
    -webkit-transition: background ease-in-out 3s, opacity 15s, border 10s;

}

#maincontent:hover{
  opacity:0.98;
background-color:black;

  border:-1px solid black;
}
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: In the line where you're setting the background you didn't close the very first `$(`. You can also use `$('.maincontent').css(...);` (also: `document.getElementById('maincontent')` works for `<div id="maincontent">` but you were using the `class` attribute)

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jbzqeon6/

Comment: background-image is the css property you're looking to set, not backgroundimage. Refer -https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-set-css-background-image-property-using-jquery.php

Comment: Thanks! but actually I mixed up the version i copied here, i just changed the above query from class to id. But it still doesn't work..

Comment: However the example from Chris is much more cleaner, I recommend using it

Comment: Fixed syntax here - https://jsfiddle.net/qk7urshc/13/

Comment: Many thanks, the jsfiddle works. When i replicate the same on dreamweaver, again the image does not load. i opened a new set of files just to replicate this portion but the image just does not load... The only change i made from codes provided were to reference the javascript to a local img on my drive rather than an internet image. Hence "https// ..."  -> "lockimg1.jpg", "lockimg2.jpg". The images are in the same level folder as the HTML and JS file itself. Is there any problem with this referencing?

Comment: Omg, thank you both!! Finally resolved by shifting script to the end of the page, and also realising that I need to include source to use Jquery (I had no idea what jquery was.. I'm basically a fresh noob. Anw, many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to define your  tag's "id" attribute.

```
(document.**getElementById**('maincontent').
```

But in yout HTML,

```
<div class="maincontent">
```

Can you add an id to your ?

```
<div class="maincontent" id="**mainContentID**">
//And change this:
(document.**getElementById**('**mainContentID**').
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually i had changed class to ID but have so many diff versions that i mixed it up. Have just amended my question above. But still doesn't work...